# Showing single value in Piechart Android

Tags: java, android, pie-chart

I don't understand, how to show single value of Piechart like below Image[image: o]

I am referring to below link for [Piecharts](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#more-exampleshttps://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/),

Below is the code which I am trying to check simple Piechart, but is shows message "No Chart Data available"

```
private void showPieChartValues() {
    try{

        ArrayList NoOfEmp = new ArrayList();

        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(945f, 0));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1040f, 1));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1133f, 2));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1240f, 3));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1369f, 4));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1487f, 5));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1501f, 6));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1645f, 7));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1578f, 8));
        NoOfEmp.add(new Entry(1695f, 9));

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(NoOfEmp, "Number");

        ArrayList year = new ArrayList();
        year.add("2008");
        year.add("2009");
        year.add("2010");
        year.add("2011");
        year.add("2012");
        year.add("2013");
        year.add("2014");
        year.add("2015");
        year.add("2016");
        year.add("2017");


        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);


        pieChart.setData(data);

        data.setValueTextSize(13f);


        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        pieChart.animateXY(5000, 5000);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please explain more detail, by send your implementation.

Comment: Hi, I have added my code, Please check and help me on this please.

Comment: Hi. Did you found the code for single value pie chart?

Answer (score 1):

It is a circular progress bar. Please check the bellow library I hope it will help you.[Circular Progress Indicator](https://github.com/antonKozyriatskyi/CircularProgressIndicator) and [Circular Progress Bar](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar)

Comment: Hi Pravin, Thanks for your response.Will above library will display one single contant value ?